# Can lookup field updates be done through flow?

Tags: configuration

I have a scenario where i need to update value from one lookup field to be another lookup field on the same object say Lead.

As this cannot be done through workflows, should we go for triggers?
Can it be done through visual flows?

Comment: Short answer, yes. What have you tried so far and what are you having trouble with?

Comment: Both trigger and flow can do this.

Comment: SFDC Learner, often the best way to learn is to try it.

Comment: I tried to implement it through flows and it worked